# Use textInput as part of the query in dbGetquery() in flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, roracle

I want to include a text input as part of the query in dbGetquery(). It shows the results in normal R script, but shows an error in renderTable().

```r
library(flexdashboard)
suppressWarnings(library(ROracle, quietly = TRUE))
library(shiny)

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
textInput(inputId = 'Col', label = 'COL', value = "")
actionButton('submit', 'Submit', icon = icon('refresh'))


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
session <- observeEvent(input$submit, {
  etf_con<- dbConnect(drv, username = load.schema.username, password = load.schema.password, dbname = load.schema.database)
  t <- dbGetQuery(etf_con, paste0("select * from table_name where col = '", input$Col, "'"))
})

renderTable({
  t
})
```

The error in the second column is:

> cannot coerce class '"function"' to a data.frame

I have also tried removing the `observeEvent` and only having `renderTable`. Like this:

```r
renderTable({
  etf_con<- dbConnect(drv, username = load.schema.username, password = load.schema.password, dbname = load.schema.database)
  dbGetQuery(etf_con, paste0("select * from table_name where col = '", input$Col, "'"))
})
```

When I hit 'Run Document', the column names show in the right column. After I put the text input, there is an error:

> non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: In `renderTable({t})` the t is a reactive function. There are a couple ways to get the data.frame from the function but the easiest is `renderTable({ t() })`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how the observeEvent will affect this. You may actually have to  `renderTable({ session() })`

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I tried `renderTable({ t(input$Col) })`, the error disppeared, but the table only has one column called V1 and the cell is the input...

Comment: I tried `renderTable({ session() })`, but the result is the same as above...

Comment: Hmm. t() is a base r function called transpose. Maybe try naming the table something that isn’t a base r function?

Comment: Another option is to declare you function to a temp variable. But this is pretty rare to need. TempOut <- my_t()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I needed a placeholder for the reactive value, so I simply added `v <- reactiveValues(t = NULL)` and use `t` as one of the element in the list `v`. Here is the link http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html. I used Pattern 3.

```
library(flexdashboard)
suppressWarnings(library(ROracle, quietly = TRUE))
library(shiny)

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
textInput(inputId = 'Col', label = 'COL', value = "")
actionButton('submit', 'Submit', icon = icon('refresh'))


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
v <- reactiveValues(t = NULL)

observeEvent(input$submit, {
  etf_con<- dbConnect(drv, username = load.schema.username, password = load.schema.password, dbname = load.schema.database)
  v$t <- dbGetQuery(etf_con, paste0("select * from table_name where col = '", input$Col, "'"))
})

renderTable({
  v$t
})
```